# get current working directory in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have code that gets the parent directory of the current file, this works when running in VScode but when I transfer the code to a Jupyter notebook it stops working.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cur_path = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__))
root_path = cur_path.parent.absolute()

train_data_path = '{}\\data\\train_codified.csv'.format(str(root_path))
test_data_path = '{}\\data\\test_codified.csv'.format(str(root_path))
```

this returns the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 7>()
      3 from pathlib import Path
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 7 cur_path = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__))
      8 root_path = cur_path.parent.absolute()
     10 train_data_path = '{}\\data\\train_codified.csv'.format(str(root_path))

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

why does the code not function in a notebook?

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced

```
cur_path = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

with

```
cur_path = Path(os.getcwd())
```

this works so my problem is solved. I am still not sure why `__file__` is not defined so if anyone knows please let me know.